# Number of subgroups of $S_6$ isomorphic to $C_3\times C_3$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I have a doubt, I do not know if my method of solving this problem is correct. I have to count how many isomorphic subgroups to $ \mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_3$ there are in $ S_6 $. being abelian I have to find two generators that switch between them, so I think you can choose a three cycle and then I have 40 choices, having the second generator forced (the other three cycle, and its power) then in all 80 choices, dividing by the number of elements of order 3 I have that ultimately there are 20 in the subgroups searched for.

Comment: Write `$\times$` for $\times$ and either `$\mathbb{Z}$` or `$\Bbb{Z}$` for $\Bbb Z$. To find out more, search online for a MathJax tutorial.

Comment: Please [edit] the question.

Comment: You have chosen each subgroup twice.

Comment: Why I choose twice the subgroup?

Comment: Might be easier to find the answer (should be 10) by listing all subgroups. You'll see why you have overcounted.

Comment: $\langle (123), (456) \rangle = \langle (456), (123) \rangle$